# How to execute an executable path returned by a powershell function?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, you can return a path in a function, and then execute the resulting variable like this:

```
Function GetMSBuildExe {
# Code that sets the value of $MSBuildExe
Return $MSBuildExe
}

$MSBuildExe= GetMSBuildExe
&$MSBuildExe MySolution.sln
```

Is there a way I can simply run the MSBuildExe without copying into a variable first? Doing this simply prints ou the GetMSBuildExe result:

```
&GetMsBuildExe MySolution.sln
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the function in parenthesis so it gets evaluated first :

`&(GetMsBuildExe) MySolution.sln`